# REST design - Get a collections of reduced ressource

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-url

I have a web service to retrieve the list of my users : /users

My User entity has a lot of attributes (with many relationship such as roles, address, etc) and it begins to be painful to retrieve the whole list.

I want to create a new web service to retrieve a list of a minimal User DTO. This DTO contains only the username, the first name and the last name.

What's your suggestions for this new URI ?

```
/users-minimal
/users/minimal
/users/func/get-minimal
... ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what's changing is merely the representation, you should make that available as a different media-type, not a different URI. For instance, if you have `application/vnd.mycompany.user.v1+json` for a normal user, you could use `application/vnd.mycompany.user-minimal.v1+json` for the minimal.

Now, you probably don't use custom media types like the above, and if you are asking about RESTful URIs, you're probably not using HATEOAS either. For those REST-like HTTP APIs, you should probably use a querystring parameter instead. Something like `/users?minimal=1` or `/users/?fields=username,first_name,last_name`.

Comment: Thank you Pedro, I will take the solution /users/?fields=username,first_name,last_name.